# How to use a rotated/scaled image as custom material in Reality Composer Pro?

Tags: realitykit, visionos, reality-composer-pro, custom-material

I am playing with custom materials in Reality Composer Pro. It is easy to add an image to the project browser and use it as diffuse color in a `MaterialXPreviewSurface` (see image). However, the text that is correctly displayed in the shader graph pane, 1) is mapped turned by 90° right in the 3D display, and 2) fills the surface of the virtual object n-times copied. I tried to turn and scale the image to get a correct display, but apparently the orientation and scale of the image has no effect.

I also tried to find a node that allows to turn or scale the input image, but could not find one. I could probably turn and scale the virtual object, apply the custom material, and maybe I could then turn and scale it back. But is this the expected procedure?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is how to make it happen:

Texcoord -> UsdTransform2D -> image

[image]

Comment: Looks good! I believe you are right, but I cannot check it, since Reality Composer Pro has disappeared in my Xcode Version 15.0.1 (15A507). Unbelievable! Are you still using Xcode 14, where it worked for me?

Comment: Oh man, where did Reality Composer Pro go, let's find it back

Comment: Andy Jazz just told me Xcode 15.1 beta 3 (15C5059c) has it again.